# Apache HTTPD 2.4 URL Rewrite Rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, digest-authentication

I've upgraded from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 and all but one type of my URL rewrite rules are working as expected.  It appears that the following rule isn't working.  I removed the IP address for security purposes.

RequestHeader unset Authorization
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /xmldb/VATIncidentPoint/(.*)$   http://x.x.x.x:8080/exist/rest/db/VATIncidentPoint/${user2group:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}}/$1 [P]

It appears what's happening is that the section including user2group is not getting replaced with the group that the user is a part of.  This results in 2 slashes at the end of the url instead of getting replaced with the group '//'.  Is there a different way to do this in 2.4 than there was in 2.2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *UPDATE* - After enable logging for mod_rewrite I was able to see that the REMOTE_USER variable isn't being set.  That is why the lookup in the user2group map is failing. Any ideas why this variable isn't working for Apache 2.4.  I know it works on 2.2 and I read about using it here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in the Location block there was 2 require statements.

Require all granted AND Require valid-user

This was causing the REMOTE_USER value to never be looked up and therefore causing nothing to be returned from the map.  Removing 'Require all granted' and leaving 'Require valid-user' solved the issue.